# Quando eu coloco o \\b no pattern.compiler ele devolve o find como falso

Tags: java, android, regex

Quando eu coloco o \b no `pattern.compiler` ele devolve o `matcher.find` como falso, porque ele não consegue achar nem um padrão justamente por causa do \b.

A seguir o código que eu uso:

```
final Pattern py = Pattern.compile("\\b(print|True|False|int|str|float|bool)\\b)");

edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    Matcher m;
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    } 
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    } 
    @Override 
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) {
        m = py.matcher(e);
        while (m.find()) {
            e.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE),m.start() ,m.end() ,0);
        }
    }
});
```

Mas se eu tirar os \b funciona mas não da maneira que eu quero.

Comment: No que você esta testando? O o pattern não nos da uma dica do real problema

Comment: Eu não tenho PC e eu compilo o java em app pelo Sketchware. Ele é uma IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que está usando o `matcher.find` de forma errada, o valor retornado por esse método muda a cada posição da sequencia de caracteres analisada.

O seu padrão está dando match e achando a palavra **print**, porém ele ainda analisa a última posição do texto (posição sinalizada pelo token `$` nesse [exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/fc8PNA/1)) e não da match, mudando o valor do matcher para `false`.

Então para o seu caso a melhor maneira é usa-lo como condição para um `while` ou `if` que mude um booleano para true se achar e usar esse valor como condição.

```
import java.util.regex.*;  
public class RegexExampleMatcher{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
  boolean achou = false;
  String content = "print";                          //String analisada                    
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bprint\\b");  //String que será usada como padrão
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);        //Matcher para usar o método find

  while(matcher.find()) {                            //Enquanto matcher.find for true
     System.out.println("Achou");                    //Imprima achou
     achou = true;                                   //muda o boolean achou para true
  }
  if (achou){
     //método que será executado
     }
}
}
```

Você pode testar esse exemplo [aqui](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler)

Comment: Mas acontece que o find é falso ,ou seja ,ele não executa nem um bloco nem o `if` nem o `while`.

Comment: Sim estou, entrada e de um `EditText` e a saída deveria ser no próprio `EditText` com uma das palavras destacadas, mas por o `Matcher` não achar nem um padrão ele não destaca essas palavras.

Answer (score 2):

Obrigado @Paz pela sua resposta mas simplesmente eu uso um app que ele usa barras em  suas string:
Ex:

`String A = "\\b";`

O que na verdade estava acontecendo era que o app pegava uma barra o java outra e só ficava o b com a string padrão sabendo disso coloquei mais uma barra ex:

```
String  a = "\\\\b";
```

Foi um desatentamento meu.